# Best model for english alphabet and digits recognition

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a fairly big dataset(over 0.5 mln 50x50 images) consisting of 62 classes in total. Images represent english alphabet and digits(all handwritten). Each class has at least 2000 samples.

I've been training Convolutional Neural Network to recognize these images with Tensorflow.

**Problem**: After quickly(about 200 training iterations) getting very close to local optima(loss values like 0.01), my classifier is stuck at around 82% accuracy on test set.

**Question**: How can I possibly get more accuracy? Is there something I do wrong with CNN? Also, is trying SVM worth it? I give details according to my CNN model below.

Random dataset entry:
[image]
**Question 2**: Besides rotating patterns, is my pre-processing methodology good? Shall I stretch patterns or leave it as it is now: with left and right margin regions with redundant white pixels.

**Details and hyperparams**:

- Tensorflow optimizer: AdamOptimizer
- learning rate alpha: `0.001`
- dropout: `1.0`(no dropout)
- mini batch size: `1500`
- number of convolutional layers: `2`
- number of pooling layers: `2`
- fully connected layers: `1`
- stride: `2` pixels
- filter size: `5` pixels
- test/train set proportion: `0.2/0.8`

**NOTE**: Paterrns aren't skeletons, they have their original widths. Images are binary with pattern being 0 value and background 1.

### UPDATE

Here's my **code** responsible for training and a tiny **subset of images**:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5kuwbyrKVqnTm1PMGZGMUxUNFU

Due to my slow internet connection I cannot afford to upload enough data. 
However, you can plot these images to decide if further pre-processing is needed.

Comment: In my opinion this is very case specific problem and cannot answer without seeing the data.  That said, I wonder if you tried image augmentation such as shifting and/or rotating of images.  This will in general increase the generalizability of your model.  Also it may be good to try some dimensionality reduction technique such as PCA since your data would have a lot of uninformative pixels.

Comment: Look for a state-of-art approach on MNIST data and first replicate that network. Look at its results, misclassified images etc. You may get some hints from that. You can see [here](http://rodrigob.github.io/are_we_there_yet/build/classification_datasets_results.html#4d4e495354) for a list of state-of-art approaches on many datasets.

Comment: I will try image augmentation. In my case patterns are centered inside a 50x50 box.  What's pretty interesting is that when I only left digits data I got up to 99% accuracy, so adding more classes decreases accuracy by far.

Answer (score 3):

It seems overfit. Your loss is 0.01, and on test set accuracy around 82%, which loss greater than 0.01(accuracy 99% about loss 0.04).

This is a specific problem. I think:

- reduce learning rate, like 1e-4
- add dropout, dropout will help reduce overfit
- reduce filter size, I think 5x5 is too big for 50x50 pic, and you could add more one convolutional layer
- your activation method, relu is a good one to reduce overfit

Not tested, this is just suggestions, BTW, if you like, give a dataset url, I'd like to train it. ;-)

Comment: One more question: Shall I stretch patterns so that they take the entire box or I can leave it as it is now: patterns are centered inside with left and right margin regions(redundant white pixels).

Comment: I'd like a snapshot also.  @KaiWen, I like your suggestion to reduce the conv size.  In addition to that, may I suggest using 3x3 conv layers and using about 6 layers of them without maxpooling.  Definitely use dropout on your fully connected layer.  The 4th rank is called depth.  Try a fairly small depth of number of classes times 2.